# How to show the tfs build logs as they are being generated in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have created a web application where i am using TFS web api. I am able to trigger a new build from my web application. I want to show the logs as they are being generated after triggering the build in a text area. I want show the build logs as they are generated generated as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate your query?

Comment: Do you use XAML build or vNext build? Can you share an example of what you want to generate?

Comment: i use vnext build

Comment: Where do you want to show the log? Try to click "Download all logs as zip" and unzip it, you'll find all logs there.

Comment: i want to show it in my text area in my web application.

Comment: How's your build definition like? Can't you see the log when you queue the build?

Comment: yes, i can see the build after i have queued in the tfs console. i am also able to get the build id for the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the build steps’/tasks’ log that have been finished by using [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build), in other words, you can’t get the step/task’s log that still in process.

Secondly, the simple code (C#) to get the build steps’ log after queue build. (Console app, you can modify it according to your requirement, for example output to web page)

1. Install [TFS Extended Client package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) to your project

Code:

```
var u = new Uri("[collection url]");
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]", "[domain]")));
            var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);

            var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
           var bd= buildServer.GetDefinitionAsync("ScrumStarain", [build definition id]).Result;


           var build= buildServer.QueueBuildAsync(new Build() { Definition =new DefinitionReference() { Id=[build definition id]}, Project= bd.Project }).Result;
            bool isFinished = false;
            int logIdCount=-1;
            bool hasEmptyLog = false;
            Dictionary<int, bool> logIds = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
            do
            {
                hasEmptyLog = false;
                Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)); //1s

                var buildLogs=buildServer.GetBuildLogsAsync("ScrumStarain", build.Id).Result;

                foreach (var l in buildLogs)
                {   
                    if(l.Url!=null&&!logIds.Keys.Contains(l.Id))
                    {
                        logIds.Add(l.Id, false);
                    }
                    if (l.Url == null)
                        hasEmptyLog = true;

                }
                IEnumerable<int> ids = logIds.Where(l => l.Value == false).Select(l2 => l2.Key).ToList();
                foreach (int id in ids)
                {
                    logIds[id] = true;
                    var buildLogStream = buildServer.GetBuildLogAsync("ScrumStarain", build.Id,id).Result;
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(buildLogStream);
                    string logContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    BuildLog bl = json_serializer.Deserialize<BuildLog>(logContent);
                    string logText = string.Join("\n", bl.value);
                    Console.WriteLine(logText);
                }
                if(logIdCount== logIds.Count)
                {
                    if(!hasEmptyLog)
                        isFinished = buildServer.GetBuildAsync(build.Id).Result.Status.ToString() == "Completed" ? true : false;
                }     
                logIdCount = logIds.Count;

            }
            while (!isFinished);
```